# in jsp,button onclick not working

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have a this java class:

```
    import java.io.*;
    public class sqlldrIam{
    public static void chargement(){
    try{
    String sqlldrCmd="SQLLDR userid=scott/tiger 
    control=C:\\Users\\imrane\\descktop\\imrane.ctl";
    System.out.println("operateur sqlldr started");
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sqlldrCmd);
    System.out.println("operateur sqlldr ended");
      }
     catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
     }}}
```

and I have this jsp page:

```
     <%@page import="dao.sqlldrIam"%>
      <%@page language="java" contentType="text/html;
       charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
       <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01
       Transactional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
       <html>
       <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Reconciliation</title>
       <style type="text/css">
       @import url(yassir.css);
       @import url(imrane.css);
       </style>
       </head>
        <body>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="C:\Users\imrane\Desktop\logo230.png"/>
        </br></br></br></br> <center>
        <h4> Données opérateur</h4>
        <input type="submit" value="Chargement opérateur" 
        onclick="<%dao.sqlldrIam.chargement();%>">
        </br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="C:\Users\imrane\Desktop\logo400.png"/>
        </body>
        </html>
```

the problem is that the onclick expects Javascript and me I give him java, then the waiter treats the code before I click on the short prop the solution is to make a function javascipt which calls on a servlet with ajax, and in the servlet one calls the method java.
but one tried several times to do that without arriving at the good code.
Thank you to give me the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can never directly invoke  Java function in Javascript.

There are two ways that you can achieve this:
1) Use ajax to post data to WebServer, you server will invoke your servlet.
See http://www.w3school.com.cn/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp ,if you are familiar with jquery.

2) Submit a form.
See http://www.w3school.com.cn/tags/tag_form.asp for general usage of form element.

Comment: i want a right code,i m begineer and am in internship and i want to continue my work in nearer time,help me.